# Get training phrases from enviroment intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to use enviroments in my dialogflow agent. And I faced with a restriction that make it imposible to get training phases from intent when using listIntent with enviroment path.
Why do I need training phrases? I'm trying to get a list of intents that I want to use as faqs. Also I need to have names of these faqs on two languages. I found only one way to store these names - in training phrases. When I started using enviroments the INTENT_VIEW_FULL option does not work and I can't form faq list anymore.
May be there is another possible solution to store faq (intent) names in two languages? Or there is a way to get training phrases when using enviroments?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-training-phrases) you need training phrases so Dialogflow knows when to match your Intents for different phrases which mean the same thing. Could you tell me if you created your main Agent already with the desired intents and training phrases? Also, I see that you are trying to create a multilingual Agent, have you followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-multilingual) in order to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have multilingual agent with intents. I already found a solution of the problem - now I use custom payload response with faq name in it.

Comment: If you found a satisfactory solution please provide it by creating a separate answering post below; i.e. not by mentioning the solution in the question itself.

Comment: I am glad you found the answer yourself. Could you post it as an answer? So it can help other community members.

Comment: I solved my problem in a different way. I store faq names in custom replay.